# How to fix ssh permission in home dir

Tags: ssh

I have trouble with my ssh config, I have directory /homa/ivan/.ssh but after my manipulation I have access denied for that derictory. At that moment I have 
`drwx------    2 root root   4096 Dec  5 14:20 .ssh`

after change owner I have

`Bad owner or permissions on /home/ivan/.ssh/config`

but I vae owner `ivan`

```
drwx------  2 ivan ivan 4096 Дек  5 14:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 32 ivan ivan 4096 Дек  5 14:03 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 ivan ivan  106 Ноя 26 22:48 config
-rwxrwxrwx  1 ivan ivan 1675 Дек  5 14:20 id_rsa
-rwxrwxrwx  1 ivan ivan  394 Дек  5 14:20 id_rsa.pub
-rwxrwxrwx  1 ivan ivan 3982 Ноя 28 19:04 known_hosts
```

how to correct tune permission for ssh config and key ?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/35079/401705

Comment: This is not about programming, so it's not on-topic for SO.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows open your gitbash terminal and type this command:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

Answer (score -1):

With the `chmod u+rwx` command. Regards.